# Deriving Euler's theorem from Fermat's little theorem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I would like to know why $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ is the same as $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, and also how Fermat's little theorem can be used to derive Euler's theorem, or vice versa.

Please keep in mind that I have little background in math, and I am trying to understand these theorems to understand the math behind RSA encryption, so I would appreciate it if the explanation could be as simple as possible (i.e. not using too much mathematical notation). I have had trouble finding resources online to explain these theorems that explain it in simple enough terms that I can understand.

Comment: First of all, those two statements ate not the same. The second is only true if $p$ does not divide $a$, while the first is true for any $a$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Right, I was reading a source online that explained that you can get from the first to the second by dividing both sides by a, if "a and p are coprime". However, it did not explain why this is the case?

Comment: For what it's worth, the names of the theorems in the title are confusing people - you are using Euler's theorem in a non-standard way. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: The "necklace proof" of fermat's little theorem is worth a read if you haven't already

Comment: @Thomas: What makes you conclude he's "using Euler's theorem in a non-standard way"? Note that he's asking two questions separated by "and also", not one question phrased in two different ways.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Because he asks an entirely unrelated question in the body of the question about a different equivalence with Fermat.

Comment: @Thomas: As I said, he's asking _two questions_ in the body. The latter of those two questions is exactly what is also asked in the question title, and I see no reason at all to assume that this second question doesn't mean what it says (both in the title and in the body).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, the title refers to the second part of my question, which is "how Fermat's little theorem can be used to derive Euler's theorem", I just didn't include the formula for Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement that $a^p\equiv a\mod p$ is the same as $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ when $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime, because in this case we can divide both sides of the congruence by $a$, and obtain one from the other.

Euler's theorem says that

$$a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\mod m,$$

where $\phi(m)$ is the number of integers less than $m$ and relatively prime to $m$. For a prime, this is exactly $p-1$, so Fermat's Little Theorem is a special case of Euler's theorem.

Comment: Kudos and +1 for the simplicity of the explanation, just as the OP asked. Not enough people here heed such requests when they're made.

Answer (score 4):

It is not obvious how to derive Euler's theorem in its full generality from Fermat's little theorem -- if the modulus has a non-trivial square factor, then Fermat's little theorem doesn't seem to provide enough.

Fortunately, for RSA you don't need Euler's theorem in its full generality; it is enough to know:

> If $p$ and $q$ are two *different* primes, then $a^{(p-1)(q-1)+1}\equiv a\pmod{pq}$ for all $a$.

Here you can start by Fermat's little theorem and then prove
$$ a^{(p-1)k+1}\equiv a \pmod p $$
for all $k$, by induction on $k$. Then do then same for $q$, and we have that
$ a^{(p-1)(q-1)+1}\equiv a $ modulo both $p$ and $q$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem now concludes the claim above.

Comment: Could you please expand on the last part? How do you combine a^{(p-1)k+1}= a mod p and a^{(q-1)k+1}= a mod q to get a^((p-1)(q-1)+1)= a mod both p and q?

Comment: @SimonZhu: Please think _just a little bit_ for yourself. If you have $a^{(p-1)k+1}\equiv a\pmod p$ and want $a^{(p-1)(q-1)+1}\equiv a\pmod p$, then at least start by comparing the two equations and find out what the difference is. The difference is that one says $k$ where the other says $q-1$. Was $k$ arbitrary? Yes it was. Is $q-1$ a possible value for an aribitrary integer? Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

**If** $a^{k-1}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, **then** $a^k\equiv a\pmod{m}$. For $a^{k-1}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ says that $m$ divides $a^{k-1}-1$. And if $m$ divides $a^{k-1}-1$, then $m$ divides $a(a^{k-1}-1)$, that is, $m$ divides $a^k-a$, and therefore $a^k\equiv a \pmod{m}$.

However, the converse does not necessarily hold. If $a^k\equiv a\pmod{m}$, we cannot necessarily conclude that $a^{k-1}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. But everything goes well if $a$ and $m$ are *relatively prime*. For suppose that $m$ divides $a^k-a$. Then $m$ divides $a(a^{k-1}-1)$. If $m$ and $a$ are relatively prime, then we can conclude that $m$ divides $a^{k-1}-1$.

Even in the special case where $m$ is the prime $p$, and $k=p$, we cannot conclude from $a^{p-1}\equiv a \pmod{p}$ that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. For let $p=7$ and $a=14$. Then $14^7\equiv 14\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, but $14^{6}$ is not congruent  to $1$ modulo $7$.

For primes we can say that **if** $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$, **and** $a$ is not divisible by $p$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

(For the first part.)

More generally, if $b\mid ac$ and $b$ and $a$ are relatively prime, then $b\mid c$. In this case, $b=p$ and $c=a^{p-1}-1$.

This more general theorem can be seen by "unique factorization," also known as the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. But it can also be proved first as a lemma for proving unique factorization.

It uses something called [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), that says that if $a,b$ are relatively prime, then there is an integer solution to $ax+by=1$. Then multiplying by $c$ you get: $acx + bcy=c$. $acx$ is divisible by $b$, by assumption, and $bcy$ is obviously divisible by $b$, so $c$ is divisible by $b$.

Answer (score 1):

They are **not** the same, if $\gcd(a,p)>1$, that is, if $p\mid a$, then $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ is true while $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ is false. It follows that the first is always true for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, but the second only in the case where $\gcd(a,p)=1$.

As for the second question, assume $\gcd(a,p)=1$, thus provided that Fermat's little theorem is true as you ask, we know that $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m$ when $m=p$, since the definition of Euler's totient function $\phi(x)$ says $\phi(p)=p-1$. In particular, $\phi(p^b)=(p-1)p^{b-1}$.

Thus, write $m=2^kp_1^{b_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{b_n}$ for given $k,b_i>0$. Since

$$\phi(m)=2^{k-1}(p_1-1)p_1^{b_1-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot(p_n-1) p_n^{b_n-1}$$

you know that

\begin{array}{ll}
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod 2\\
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod{p_1}\\
&\vdots\\
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod{p_n}\\
\end{array}

because for each case $p_i-1$ is in the exponent for a given $i-th$ prime (for 2 it is trivial).

The last step is to show that $a^{(p-1)p^{b-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{p^b}$. Notice that by showing this we can conclude that

\begin{array}{ll}
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod 2\\
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod{p_1^{b_1}}\\
&\vdots\\
a^{\phi(m)}&\equiv 1\pmod{p_n^{b_n}}\\
\end{array}

and from the fact that all divide $a^{\phi(m)}-1$ it would be safe to conclude that $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$.

So, to prove that $a^{(p-1)p^{b-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{p^b}$ is the tricky part. We know that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, but that a power $p^b$ must divide $a^{(p-1)p^{b-1}}-1$ is not trivial. To prove this fact, I use an old friend called Lifting the Exponent Lemma -- LTE (link: [Lifting the Exponent Lemma](http://www.taharut.org/imo/LTE.pdf)).

It says: let $\gcd(x, p)=\gcd(y, p)=1$ for a prime $p$ and given whole numbers $x,\ y$, where $v_p$ is the maximum exponent $b$ such that $p^b\mid\ell$, for $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $v_p(x^n\pm y^n)=v_p(x\pm y)+v_p(n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

From that we conclude that $v_p(a^{(p-1)p^{b-1}}-1^{(p-1)p^{b-1}})=v_p(a^{p-1}-1^{p-1})+v_p(p^{b-1})$, so clearly $a^{(p-1)p^{b-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{p^b}$.

I should say that the proof given by Euler is more economic and elegant. We don't need to actually *use* Fermat's little theorem to get Euler's theorem only because one is a particular case of the other.

Comment: The link is expired.