# number theory | proving a stage of Euler's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question:
By given - $n > 1, n\in\mathbb{N},$ when $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot...\cdot p_k^{a_k}$, and $b \in\mathbb{N}$, need to prove that $\forall i\in[k]$, if $gcd(p_i,b)=1$, then $p_i^{a_i}|b^{\varphi(n)}-1$.

I tried to use the next: $\varphi(n)=n(1-1/p_1)\cdot...\cdot(1-1/p_k)$, but then I don't know how to say that $p_i^{a_i}$ divides $b^{n}\cdot b^{(1-1/p_1)\cdot...\cdot(1-1/p_k)}
$, when $p_i$ isn't a part of b's factorization.  So i decided to assume that : $gcd(p_i,b)>1$ and I got that $p_i \mid  b^{\varphi(n)}$ so $p_i^{a_i} \nmid  b^{\varphi(n)}-1$ so $gcd(p_i,b)=1$. But it feels like i'm missing something, because I need to use polynomial division, or a theorem which uses a polynomial division.

Therefore, I will be glad if you will give me a direction or a hint. Thank you!

Comment: The trick here is to find minimal solutions for each prime.  The thing is 'weakly multiplicative', which p(ab) = p(a)p(b) if a and b are coprime.  p is a random function.

Comment: You can use LTE or rquivalent, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1382508/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque what does this has to do with using polynomial division?

Comment: @BillDubuque I am still waiting for your answer. :)

Comment: A proof that way is already in the link I gave.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you Bill! :)